# What word (adverb, preferably) can we use to show that we need to study harder and cover more stuff than usual in a short amount of time?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, vocabulary

"We need to study ___________(ly) in order to not fall behind."

Being a non-native speaker, I'm thinking of the words "compactly" and "compressedly" (whose translations are exactly what we use in Farsi in such situations). But I don't think those would be natural-sounding in English.

Edit: Obviously, "hard" wouldn't fit well there since it doesn't emphasize "a lot of stuff in a short amount of time"

Comment: We need to study [**diligently**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/diligently), but the question title isn't the same as its body. The title suggests you need to "catch up".

Comment: We need to study more. We need to study harder. If you want to sound natural, keep it simple. Or use an idiom. We need to kick it up a notch. We need to step up our game.

Comment: To address the edit made to the question, *harder* certainly does fit in the sense of "a lot of stuff in a short amount of time." If you study *harder*, you are also studying *faster*. (It's more difficult to study more in the same amount of time.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Hi. Yeah I guess as Mr. Dwight pointed out, keeping it simple is the way to sounding natural. I also found the word "efficiently". I guess that would fit well too.